# Code depending on which user is logged

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a blog in MVC, I need to know if the `admin` is logged, and if is logged then show him links for `delete, edit`, and `create` posts, for the other users they don't need to see those links, I was thinking in use a `boolean` `Session` variable for this, the value of the variable is `true` if `admin` is logged, otherwise `false`, I have read that we should avoid to use `Session` variables. Do you think is a good practice to do this using `Session` variable?
I know that using `[Authorize(Users ="admin@email.com")]` I can give or deny access to actions depending on which user is logged. 
But how could I know IF the admin is logged using a condition?

For example: `if(someCode.GiveMeUserNameLogged == "admin@email.com" ){//do other code}` ???

Comment: If you're using roles then you can just do `if(User.IsInRole("admin"))`. You gotta be more specific.

Comment: Take it a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087786/how-should-i-check-if-a-user-is-authenticated-in-mvc5

Answer (score 1):

I can do what I want with this sentence: `if(User.Identity.Name=="adminUser"){//do some other stuff}`